# How to get the extension of file in Flutter?

Tags: file, flutter, dart, file-management

My goal is to identify the extension of a file through code like whether a given file is a .doc,.pdf,.svg etc.

One thing is to get it through the extension present at the end of the file's name. But what if the extension is not present in the file's name?

Another thing I tried is to determine it through initial bytes of the file.
eg: .docx extension file starts with : [80,75,3,4,20,0,6, .....]
In this case, I only know some of them. So where can I find initial bytes of all types of extensions ?

I think the second process is a valid way to do it but is there any other good way to determine the extension of a file ?

Comment: Possibly related, does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58289813/how-to-check-if-the-given-path-is-of-image-or-video

Comment: I tried this our just now ......... But even this package determines its type based on the extension provided at the end of file's name ........ It gave an exception when I removed the extension from a pdf's name and when I changed the extension at the end of the name from .pdf to .xls ......It chagned the output accordingly.

Comment: If the extension isn't present in the filename, you have precisely two options: check the file for header information (if it exists) and see if it matches a known format, or try to open the file in some program or library that accepts particular file types and see if it works. (To find the header values of different file types, google "X file specification" and something will usually come up.)

Comment: Also, if someone sends you a file without a file extension, mime type, metadata file, or some other agreed-upon way to know what the file type is, a third option might be to track them down at their office and punch them in the face for being so stupidly cryptic or "efficient" in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So where can I find initial bytes of **all types** of extensions ?

You can start with this these two:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures
2. [https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html](https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.htm)

But there are many, many file types out there... it is quite possible you will never be able to find them **all**.

I would only use "Magic Bytes" when absolutely necessary , like salvaging data from a poorly thought out db that has blobs and doesn't keep track of what kind of file is in each blob... because at the end of the day it is still a hacky way to get the job done. If possible just reject file types without proper extensions.